# Transferring text using EditText widget

Tags: android, parsing, layout, android-edittext

I saw an answer earlier but it didn't help much, my question is :
I have 2 EditText widgets and a button on my layout, what I want is that when a calculation is performed in EditText1, and the calculate button is clicked. the ans to the calculation should be shown in EditText2. 
I'll appreciate all opinions and suggestions thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do something like this : 
in your `onCreate` method of your activity :

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);  
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id); 
EditText firstEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_first_edit_text_id); 
EditText secondEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_second_edit_text_id);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do what you want
        secondEditText.setText("yourString");

    }
});
```

press ctrl+shift+o and eclipse will add imports automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but Pls does the above require any import ? And is the 'button' a system variable or you have to create it yourself. Im pretty new to this so pls spare my questions if they sound out of place.